# closing a lightbox by clicking a button and outside

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox

I am struggling to figure out how to add the ability to close the Lightbox by clicking on the backdrop or dark area and also adding a close button to the light box to close it off.

```
<script>

$("a#show-panel").click(function(){
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
 })
 $("a#close-panel").click(function(){
     $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
 })

 </script>
```

I am using this example: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HjCyA/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Check this updated fiddle

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HjCyA/71/)

```
$("#close-panel,#lightbox").click(function(){
 $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
})
```

Comment: There is an issue where if you click anywhere eon the Lightbox is closes it?

Comment: A note to go with this: set your backdrop to fixed position so that in case the user scrolls the backdrop is always in view